# How to encode & in URL that isn't part of the query parameter?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am getting data out of XML and constructing a url to pass to Pinterest.

The Pinterest URL structure is

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=[URL]&media=[media URL]&description=[description]
```

For reasons beyond my control, the [description] field in the XML has a literal ampersand character.  Example: "Peanut Butter & Jelly Sandwich"

If I try to place this entire Pinterest URL into encodeURIComponent(), that & becomes %26, but it's not a query parameter &.

Expected output should hopefully be:
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Frecipe%2Fpeanut-butter-jelly-sandwich.html&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com/images/pbjs.jpg&description=Peanut%20Butter%20%26%20Jelly%20Sandwich

What options are there in XSLT 1.0 or JS to help me deal with that?

EDIT 1: Added expected output.

EDIT 2: It turns out there was another piece of code performing redirects in our site, and it required special characters after itself to be encoded.  It created an incompatibility.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What, precisely, is wrong with replacing the & with %26? See, for example, https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=black+%26+decker or https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://pjb.example.com&description=Peanut+Butter+%26+Jelly

Comment: @JoyceBabu: Added expected output.

Comment: @Rob: For some reason, %26 gets changed back to & as the URL is passed to Pinterest.  I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if Pinterest is escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[description]` before adding it to the url.

```
"https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=[URL]&media=[media URL]&description=" + escape("Peanut Butter & Jelly Sandwich")
```

Or you could do

```js
var data = {
    url: 'http://google.com',
    media: 'http://media/url',
    description: 'Peanut Butter & Jelly Sandwich'
};
var pinterest_url = 'https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=[url]&media=[media]&description=[description]';
for (var key in data) {
    pinterest_url = pinterest_url.replace("[" + key + "]", escape(data[key]));
}

alert(pinterest_url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  I found that another piece of code on our site required anything after itself in the URL to be escaped, so it was causing this problem with ampersands.  That piece of code is not compatible, so we're forced to remove it.  Once we do that, the rest of the URL can follow normal conventions.